# how can I write a promise within another promise in async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm quite new to Node.js and I'm trying to build a pagination feature for my "Get all users" page in async/await. But I seem to have bumped into a hurdle and after an extensive research (both here, other sources and even tutorials), I still can't come up with a solution. All the solutions I've seen show me how to do either.
This is the code:

```
mongoOp.countDocuments({},function(err,totalCount) {
  if(err) {
    response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"}
  }
  mongoOp.find({},{},query,function(err,data) {
      // Mongo command to fetch all data from collection.
    if(err) {
        response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
    } else {
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / size)
        response = {"error" : false,"message" : data,"pages": totalPages};
    }
    res.json(response);
  });
});
```

I have figured out how to write both countDocuments() and find() functions in async/await to produce results as the following send correct json responses:

The countDocuments() function

```
 try {
    totalDocs = await mongoOp.countDocuments();
    return res.status(200).json({totalDocs})
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send(err)
  }
};
```

The find() query:

```
try {
    const users = await mongoOp.find({}, {}, query);
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: users
   });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
```

However, I don't know how to put them together to produce the needed results.
I would be very grateful if I could be assisted.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for

```
try {
    const totalCount = await mongoOp.countDocuments();
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / size)
    const data = await mongoOp.find({}, {}, query);
    return res.status(200).json({"error":false, "message":data, "pages":totalPages});
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({"error":true, "message":"Error fetching data"});
}
```